# How to get "git diff" information from one pipeline to another

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have PR pipeline in which I build Dockerfiles, but only those which are changed. I get paths of changed files using git diff command. After PR is completed the source branch is merged but not deleted. I have release pipeline on main branch which is triggered after merge to main. This pipeline will perform same build only on changed files and then push those images to container registry.

But git diff in this pipeline wont work since agent is checked out on main branch. How can I get the same information in this pipeline? I looked up git log command in which I could do git diff against commitId but that wont work If someone else will finish their PR before me. The PR branch still exist, is it possible to somehow get name of this branch in the release pipeline?

Comment: 1. "This pipeline will perform same build only on changed files" - What exactly are the "changed files" you are talking about? In which branch are these "changed files" located? 2. Your release pipeline is triggered after merge, and the main branch already has the latest changes. Why do you still need to "perform same build only on changed files"? 3. ”is it possible to somehow get name of this branch in the release pipeline“ - When you say "PR branch", do you only mean the source branch of your own PR pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what files changed in top-commit/merge of main, you can compare both its parents.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^1 HEAD^2
```

If you're concerned that additional files were changed within the merge commit itself, you could also compare the top-commit with the commit before. However, this command will **not** fail if the top-commit isn't a merge.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~ HEAD
```

(instead of `HEAD` you could be more specific and e.g. use `origin/main`)

Comment: 'git diff --name-only HEAD^1 HEAD^2' gives me: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Then your HEAD isn't a merge. Instead of "HEAD" you could use the sha of the merge commit instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I looked up git log command in which I could do git diff against commitId but that wont work If someone else will finish their PR before me. The PR branch still exist, is it possible to somehow get name of this branch in the release pipeline?

Since someone else could also finish PR before you, it's hard to make sure the branch get from `git diff` is expected.

To transfer the data between two pipelines (PR build and release pipeline), you can use artifact feature.

You can get the source branch(or git diff content) on PR build pipeline, put it in a txt file, publish it as an artifact. On your release pipeline, you can download the artifact,parse the text for the content needed.